# set height of p:tabView

Tags: primefaces, tabview

I'm using PrimeFaces and I have a tabView at the top of the page, and the page content under this tab panel. However when using orientation="left", the tabbed panel's height is too big:

[image]

If I use the horizontal orientation it looks fine, although there is still a small margin:

[image]

I've tried overriding .ui-tabs-nav height but that didn't seem to do anything. How can I set the height so it fits the content displayed inside the tabs?

Comment: Open the page in a browser developer tool and see if your change in style is actually applied or overruled by a more specific selector. I'm pretty sure the latter is happening.

Comment: I have found .ui-tabs-left, tried overriding that as well (in style tag in the html), doesnt seem to work :s

Comment: Then read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity and try to make a more specific selector... (or the same one but later in the order)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem using the following, looks like I had cache issues:

```
.ui-tabs-left > .ui-tabs-nav {
    height: auto !important;
}
```